# Extract root, month letter-year and yellow key from a Bloomberg futures ticker

Tags: regex, matlab, bloomberg

A Bloomberg futures ticker usually looks like:

```
MCDZ3 Curcny
```

where the root is `MCD`, the month letter and year is `Z3` and the 'yellow key' is `Curcny`.

Note that the **root** can be of variable length, 2-4 letters or 1 letter and 1 whitespace (e.g. `S H4 Comdty`).
The **letter-year** allows only the letter listed below in `expr` and can have two digit years. 
Finally the **yellow key** can be one of several security type strings but I am interested in `(Curncy|Equity|Index|Comdty)` only.

In **Matlab** I have the following regular expression

```
expr = '[FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{1,2} '; 
[rootyk, monthyear] = regexpi(bbergtickers, expr,'split','match','once');
```

where

```
rootyk{:}
ans = 
    'mcd'    'curncy'
```

and

```
monthyear = 
    'z3 '
```

I don't want to match the ' ' (space) in the monthyear. How can I do?

Comment: That format is typical for future contracts but not equities for example, which also have the exchange, as in "IBM US Equity"...

Comment: @assylias Thanks, edited title and body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no leading or trailing whitespaces and only upcase letters in the root, this should work:

```
^([A-Z]{2,4}|[A-Z]\s)([FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{1,2}) (Curncy|Equity|Index|Comdty)$
```

You've got root in the first group, letter-year in the second, yellow key in the third.

I don't know Matlab nor whether it covers Perl Compatible Regex. If it fails, try e.g. with  instead of `\s`. Also, drop the `^...$` if you'd like to extract from a bigger source text.

Comment: Verbose but diligent in applying all the requirements. I confirm that Matlab supports the above expression. For a Matlab example please see [Eitan T's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20628456/2180721).

Answer (score 2):

The expression you're feeding `regexpi` with contains a space and is used as a pattern for `'match'`. This is why the matched `monthyear` string also has a space<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to keep it simple and let `regexpi` do the work for you (instead of postprocessing its output), try a different approach and capture tokens instead of matching, and ignore the intermediate space:

```
%//     <$1><----------$2---------> <$3>
expr = '(.+)([FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{1,2}) (.+)';
tickinfo = regexpi(bbergtickers, expr, 'tokens', 'once');
```

You can also simplify the expression to a more genereic `'(.+)(\w{1}\d{1,2})\s+(.+)'`, if you wish.

#### Example

```
bbergtickers = 'MCDZ3 Curncy';
expr = '(.+)([FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{1,2})\s+(.+)'; 
tickinfo = regexpi(bbergtickers, expr, 'tokens', 'once');
```

The result is:

```
tickinfo =
    'MCD'
    'Z3'
    'Curncy'
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This expression is also used as a delimiter for `'split'`. Removing the trailing space from it won't help, as it will reappear in the `rootyk` output instead.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of note 1. For some reason I did not want to tokenize, but I guess it was just mental framing. In all fairness, although I prefer your answer, [svoop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20617793/2180721) is basically the same, more robust but verbose. So, I am gonna combine the two, I will enforce the yellow key and your generic root match.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Whatever works best for you. I'm glad my answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to get rid of the leading and or trailing spaces at the edge, there is a very simple command for that:

```
monthyear = trim(monthyear)
```

For removing all spaces, you can do:

```
monthyear(isspace(monthyear))=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different approach, basically this searches the letter before your year number:

```
s = 'MCDZ3 Curcny'
p = regexp(s,'\d')
s(min(p)
s(min(p)-1:max(p))
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid post processing.